waiting for visibility of element located by By.id: btnNew (tried for 35 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)
public void navigateToAssets() {
    WebElement clickOnAssets = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//li//a//span[contains(text(),'Assets')]")));
    clickOnAssets.click();
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("btnNew"))); 
}

and after that deciding the page is loaded, going with other methods in flow, gave wait 35seconds, i just dont want that exception to occur

what's the question?
